# MultiAutoCompleteTextView remains null in AlertDialog builder

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a mobile application with a button that should create an Alert dialog with a search bar in it, However for some reason i can't  get the MultiAutoCompleteTextView to work with it as it keeps giving me KotlinNullPointerExceptions. and adding nullpointer safety will just skip the setting the adapter.

```
addItem.setOnClickListener {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
        val alertview = View.inflate(this, R.layout.content_searchproduct, null)
        val itemsList = listOf("Item1","items2","Btem3","btem4")
        builder.setView(alertview)

        val textfield =builder.findViewById<MultiAutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.textidplaceholder)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList)
        textfield!!.setAdapter(adapter)

        textfield.threshold = 1
        builder.textidplaceholder.setTokenizer(MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer())



        builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Add") { _: DialogInterface?, _: Int -> searchProducts(textfield.text.toString()) }
        builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Cancel") { _: DialogInterface?, _: Int -> }
        builder.show()


    }
```

Comment: you are getting id by wrong view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this :

```
val textfield =alertview.findViewById<MultiAutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.textidplaceholder)
```

instead of :

```
val textfield =builder.findViewById<MultiAutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.textidplaceholder)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. will come back to upvote as soon as i get enough rep